# azure VPN not working on windows server 2012

Tags: azure, windows-server-2012, azure-vpn

I created a VPN gateway on azure and I was able to connect to it using windows 10. However it does not work on windows server 2012. I got this error.

`The connection was prevented because of a policy configured on your RAS/VPN server. Specifically, the authentication method used by the server to verify your username and password may not match the authentication method configured in your connection profile. Please contact the Administrator of the RAS server and notify them of this error. (Error 812)`

In azure the authenticate type is Azure certificate.

I have tried some solutions online, like running some commands and applying some windows updates, but nothing worked.

Comment: Did you enable TLS 1.2 on your server 2012?

Comment: I am having a hard time enabling it on windows server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Like the comment mentioned, Azure VPN Gateway supports only TLS 1.2. To maintain support, see the [updates to enable support for TLS1.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vpn-faq#tls1). and more details: [Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Windows.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi)

Also, Windows OS versions prior to Windows 10 are not supported with IKEv2 VPN and can only use SSTP or OpenVPN® Protocol. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-vpn-faq#does-azure-support-ikev2-vpn-with-windows).

Check the above all. If you still have any question, you can [contact the MS Azure support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/4026305/sql-contact-microsoft-azure-support) check if there is any update on the Azure side.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use openvpn as a tunel type and it worked.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes across the same error ("*The connection was prevented because of a policy configured on your RAS/VPN server..*"), here's what helped in my case:

1. In the Windows search for "ncpa.cpl" or just go to Network Connections
2. Right click on your VPN connection and open properties
3. In the Security tab, tick checkboxes next to the "Challenge Handshake.." and/or "Microsoft CHAP.."